# Simple field extension's endomorphism is trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Denote $C=\bar{K}$ algebraic closure of field $K$ and $E/K$ some finite field extension. Since the separable degree of field extension $E/K$ is defined as $|Hom(E/K, C/K)|$ instead of $|End(E/K)|$ where both $Hom,End$ means the set $K-$algebra homomorphism and endomorphisms, I would like to compute the simple extension's endormorphism and check whether it is trivial.

Suppose $E=K(a)$ where $a$ algebraic over $K$. So $E\cong K^n$ for some $n\in N$. $End(E/K)\cong K^{n^2}$ as $K$ vector space.

1. However, not all of them are $K-$algebra homomorphism.

Clearly $Id_{K(a)}\in End(K(a)/K$. Any endomorphism of field extension is injecitve and thus isomorphism between $K(a)/K$ and $K(a)/K$. So some element $b\in K(a)$ is being sent to $a\in K(a)/K$. So $K(a)=K(b)$. $a$ and $b$ must differ by a non-zero element of $K$.(i.e $f(a)=k'a,k'\in K^{\star}$). So $|End(E/K)|=|K^{\star}|$ where $K^{\star}$ are non-zero elements.

2. How do I identify the morphism between $End(E/K)$ and $K^{\star}$? Identify them as group? Does this happen to be in Abelian category?
3. I should expect $|Hom(E/K,C/K)|\geq |End(E/K)|$. For simple finite extension I do not see this unless I have made error above.

Comment: I'm lost by the end of line 1: what is $C$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $C$ is algebraic closure of $K$. I do not believe I am working in Abelian category.

Comment: Next: you have "$E\cong K^n$". Not an isomorphism in the category of $K$-algebras?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That should be isomorphism in $K-$vector space sense. Not in the category of $K-$algebras.

Comment: It’s true that, in your notation, $f(a)=k'a$, but there will be very few elements $k'\in K^\star$ which arise this way. So your statement that $|End(E/K)|=|K^\star|$ is not justified, and indeed is very far from true.

Comment: Next: "$a$ and $b$ must differ by a non-zero element of $K$". I don't believe this for a moment.

Comment: @Lubin Can you clarify a bit why not all of them will come from $K^{\star}$? Do I expect $|End(E/K)|\leq |Hom(E/K,C/K)|$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $b$ and $a$ must satisfies the same minimal polynomial. Either they are the same root or they are distinct. I am assuming $f$ has non-repeated roots in algebraic closure. Sorry for the confusion. As this is my random thought, when I am reading the field theory.

Comment: The endomorphism set is always finite. And every $K$-endomorphism of $E$ is certainly a field homomorphism of $E$ into $C$.

Comment: The quotient $b/a$ will lie in $K(a)$, but not in general in $K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to look at your situation is to consider the minimal polynomial for $a$, say $g(X)\in K[X]$, and to ask how many *other* roots of $g$ lie in $K(a)$. Depending on $a$ (equivalently, on $g$) there may be no other roots lying in $K(a)$, or all roots of $g$ may be there. This is the core of the concept of normality of an extension.